# RewriteRule relative to subdirectory the htaccess is in

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have an site subdirectory, with the .htaccess in it:

```
www.example.com/projA
/var/www/html/projA/.htaccess
```

I want to redirect all `www.example.com/projA/*` to my file at `/var/www/html/projA/index.php`

I currently have the following, which works:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . /projA/index.php [L]
```

but since my .htaccess file is inside of the projA folder already, is there a way to write this rule so that I don't need to reference projA at all? E.g. if the base path could be relative to .htaccess location, I'd just want to specify this:

```
RewriteRule . ./index.php [L]
```

I don't want to reference "projA" because it's a path that may change often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove reference to projA by putting the htaccess in your projA folder and use relative path in your rewrite rule.
Put your htaccess in /var/www/html/projA/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
# enable the following line if you want to serve directories directly (without index.php)
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# enable the following line if you have any other files on you want to serve directly
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !=index.php

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1  [NC,QSA]
```